# Impact on changing license

Tags: licensing

Someone forked my repository on GitHub and I'm planning on changing the license where forking is not allowed. What should I do? Can I force the user that forked my repository to delete it? Or does he have the right to keep it?

Comment: No, the version he forked is still under the original license. If he 'rebases' though, that could be a different story. I suggest creating a new (private) repo in this case.

Comment: It depends upon the past licence. If that past license was e.g. MIT or GPL (and probably in most other cases) you cannot force the forking user to delete.

Comment: The previous license was WTFPL.

Comment: I changed the license to GPL 2.0.

Comment: + 1 for using *WTFPL*. Btw. WTFPL is not the license do *force* someone ... X-D

Comment: @ollo True. That can be a big advantage and a big disadvantage unfortunately :(

Comment: This question is off topic as it is about legal issues, not about a programming problem. Ask a lawyer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous license is valid for his fork since back then you gave him that rights. License changes can't be made "backwarts" into past.

> I'm planning on changing the license where forking is not allowed.

This is taking effect at the day you release your project under the new license.

> What should I do?

Not much. You may ask him to delete it, but with your License you granted him the rights under the therms of the license. You can't take him those rights later.

> Can I force the user that forked my repository to delete it?

If he respects the terms of your license you can't.

> Or does he have the right to keep it?

He has that granted rights until he does something that makes the license invalid.

**Just a remark:** If someone forks your project this means it's something useful to him or something he may improve - be proud of that!